# I want to convert this list into WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I want to convert this list you toggle the image to WordPress I converted but I can convert the following link only and not the image that appears with the following link I want to convert this list into WordPress 
This is a simple code list This is the link image
https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=668433036658047&set=o.1822460564644800&type=3&theater&notif_t=photo_comment&notif_id=1476095261437445

```html
<div class="page_content_menu">
       <nav class="main-nav">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index-2.html"><img src="images/icons/white/home.png" alt="" title="" /><span>Home</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="about.html"><img src="images/icons/white/user.png" alt="" title="" /><span>About</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="features.html"><img src="images/icons/white/settings.png" alt="" title="" /><span>Features</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="photos.html"><img src="images/icons/white/photos.png" alt="" title="" /><span>Gallery</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="videos.html"><img src="images/icons/white/video.png" alt="" title="" /><span>Videos</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="blog.html"><img src="images/icons/white/blog.png" alt="" title="" /><span>Blog</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="tables.html"><img src="images/icons/white/tables.png" alt="" title="" /><span>Tables</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="form.html"><img src="images/icons/white/form.png" alt="" title="" /><span>Inputs</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="slider.html"><img src="images/icons/white/slider.png" alt="" title="" /><span>Slider</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="toggle.html"><img src="images/icons/white/toogle.png" alt="" title="" /><span>Toggle</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="tabs.html"><img src="images/icons/white/docs.png" alt="" title="" /><span>Tabs</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#" data-popup=".popup-social" class="open-popup"><img src="images/icons/white/heart.png" alt="" title="" /><span>Social</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#" data-popup=".popup-login" class="open-popup"><img src="images/icons/white/lock.png" alt="" title="" /><span>Login</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="tel:1234 5678" class="external"><img src="images/icons/white/phone.png" alt="" title="" /><span>Call Now</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.html"><img src="images/icons/white/contact.png" alt="" title="" /><span>Contact</span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>  
      <div class="close_popup_button"><a href="#" class="backbutton"><img src="images/icons/white/menu_close.png" alt="" title="" /></a></div>
     </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by convert it into Wordpress? Do you know what Wordpress is?

Comment: I want to convert image menu to WordPress The picture is in the following link https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=668433036658047&set=o.1822460564644800&type=3&theater&notif_t=photo_comment&notif_id=1476095261437445